# lockboxes problem: list inside a list and each list contains keys to unlock the other boxes

Tags: python, nested-lists

Here is the problem:
You have n number of locked boxes in front of you. Each box is numbered sequentially from 0 to n - 1 and each box may contain keys to the other boxes.

boxes is a list of lists

A key with the same number as a box opens that box

You can assume all keys will be positive integers

The first box boxes[0] is unlocked

Return True if all boxes can be opened, else return False

This is my code but I have found in some cases that it takes all the values of the lists and stores them even the ones that can't be unlocked:

```
def canUnlockAll(boxes):
    newlist = []
    k = len(boxes)
    for i in boxes:
        if len(i) == 0 and i is not boxes[k-1]:
            return False
        for j in i:
            newlist.append(j)
    print(newlist)
    for index, keys in enumerate(boxes):
        if index in newlist or index < k-1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And this is the test case I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

canUnlockAll = __import__('0-lockboxes').canUnlockAll

boxes = [[1, 4, 6], [2], [0, 4, 1], [5, 6, 2], [3], [4, 1], [6], [7]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes), "\t: False")
print('-----------------------------')
```

My issue is how to fix the issue where the box in index 7 is unlocked while it shouldn't be unlocked!

Comment: Your final `for` loop doesn't do what you want.  Based *solely* on the first box, you return either True or False; none of the other boxes gets considered at all.

Comment: @jasonharper it is my first time using enumerate but I want to fix the problem of only iterating through the first box

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
def join(T,R):
  res =[]
  for e in R:
    res += T[e]
  return res

def canUnlockAll(boxes):
  index = 0
  total = list(set(boxes[0])| {0})
  added = True
  while added:
    added = False
    for j in join(boxes,total[index:]):
      if j not in total:
        total.append(j)
        index +=1
        added= True
  print(total)
  
  return len(total)==len(boxes)
```

Tests :

```
boxes = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [0]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes), "\t: True\n")

boxes = [[1, 4, 6], [2], [0, 4, 1], [5, 6, 2], [3], [4, 1], [6], [7]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes), "\t: False")
```

Results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
True    : True

[0, 1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5]
False   : False
```

Comment: That code works like a charm thanks! but my code must return either True if all boxes can be unlocked or False, so the last return statement isn't a solution and I didn't understand the code very well as I am a beginner but thanks alot it worked in all edge cases!

Comment: @YassinBahri if all the boxes were oppened then we have all the keys! total list has the keys of the boxes which are the key to case 0 and the keys in the box that has the index 0. (`boxes[0]` is oppened) and now as long as we add new keys `added = True` we loop again to check. once we can't add anymoe keys we verify the number of keys in the list `total` and the number of the boxes by doing   `len(total)==len(boxes)` and that returns True of all the boxes were oppened and False if not ( if total is missing a key)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar task and this is the code I used.
I've tested it with your test case and it worked. Maybe you can try it.

```
def canUnlockAll(boxes):
    unlocked = [0]
    for box_id, box in enumerate(boxes):
        if not box:
            continue
        for key in box:
            if key < len(boxes) and key not in unlocked and key != box_id:
                unlocked.append(key)
    if len(unlocked) == len(boxes):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

[✨SOLVED] This is the Fastest|Simplest way I could find:

```
def canUnlockAll(boxes):
    """ Method that determines if all boxes can be opened """

    for key in range(1, len(boxes)):
        flag = False
        for box in range(len(boxes)):
            if key in boxes[box] and box != key:
                flag = True
                break
        if not flag:
            return False

    return True
```

✅ Passed all Test cases with success

```
boxes = [[]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes))

boxes = [[1], [2], [3], [4], []]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes))

boxes = [[1, 4, 6], [2], [0, 4, 1], [5, 6, 2], [3], [4, 1], [6]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes))

boxes = [[1, 4], [2], [0, 4, 1], [3], [], [4, 1], [5, 6]]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes))

boxes = [[], [2], [1], [4], []]
print(canUnlockAll(boxes))
```